# Provides Microsoft Botframework built-in retrieval of profile images for Facebook or Skype?

Tags: botframework, skype, facebook-messenger

We are running a bot based on Microsoft Botframework using Facebook Messenger and Skype channels.

We are logging each message to database and displaying conversations in a report and we would like to display profile image next to each conversation.

We receive `userId` for each incoming message and we can load profile image by using:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{userId}/picture

http://api.skype.com/users/{userId}/profile/avatar
```

But is there in Botframework some "built-in" mechanism to do that for Facebook Messenger and/or Skype?

The motivation is to have "general" solution without custom code for channels that we might enable in the future.

Comment: Short answer: no there is no built-in mechanism for that, but you can develop and share it on github, that would be great!